# Compare ASCII value in sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

Database table contains  columns called 'name', 'nameInASCII'. Which have value

```
'SABARI DAS',
'83 65 66 65 82 73 32 68 65 83'
```

respectively. I want to write query for getting above row even if the input 'name' variable is in swap order.(ex : DAS SABARI). How is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

The only simple/quick option which comes to mind would be to make a judicious use of the `LIKE` operator and just search for components of the name separately, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE name LIKE '%SABARI%' AND name LIKE '%DAS%';
```

If this would not be specific enough, then full text search might be another option:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE yourVirtualTable USING FTS5(name, nameInASCII);
INSERT INTO yourVirtualTable (name, nameInASCII)
VALUES
    ('SABARI DAS', '83 65 66 65 82 73 32 68 65 83');
```

With full text search setup, now we can search for both a given first and last name at the same time:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourVirtualTable
WHERE yourVirtualTable MATCH 'SABARI AND DAS';
```

The results of the above query would not change were we to match `DAS AND SABARI`, i.e. the order of search terms does not matter.